# Alternative to Double Iteration

Tags: python, iteration

I have a procedure which requires me to check each value in a List against every other value in the same List. If I identify something that meets some requirement, I add it to another List to be removed after this procedure is finished.

Pseudo-code:

```
for value1 in my_list:
    for value2 in my_list:
        if meets_requirements(value1, value2):
            to_be_removed.append(value2)
```

This looks ugly to me. Naming conventions for the variables are difficult to assign or understand. There's the potential (although very un-likely, in this case) I could accidentally modify the list while iterating it. There may be issues with performance.

**Is there a better alternative to performing these double iterations?**

If not, are there any ways I can make this more readable and "feel" like quality code?

Comment: Check out `itertools`, specifically `product` and `combinations`

Comment: Can you clarify whether `my_list` is supposed to refer to the same list in both places?  Or do `value1` and `value2` come from separate lists?

Comment: @MarkDickinson - Same list

Comment: What sort of 'requirements' are involved? Is it something that could be used to presort the list, to reduce the number of tests needed? Are they transitive, ie does meets_requirements(value1, value2) imply meets_requirements(value2, value1)? Can you calculate possible values of value2 from knowing value1?

Comment: Basically, I am identifying and removing sub-strings of other Strings in the same list. Sort of a de-duplication if you will. The only catch is that each String has an associated 'count' and if the the count of the Strings is too different (delta > 10) then I do not remove it. Sorry for being so vague -- an NDA is keeping me from disclosing too much. Let me know if that helps at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to find the removed values first. Just create the list you need in one shot:

```
my_list = [y for y in my_list 
             if not any(meets_requirement(x,y) for x in my_list)]
```

Comment: And although it's not necessarily equivalent, it's probably better to remove the `[]` from inside the `any()` and let it short-circuit. Provided `meets_requirement` has no side-effects it would have the same result.

Comment: Thanks! I like your suggestion.

Comment: From some quick, non-scientific tests on 'real data' I found that using this method as opposed to `itertools.product` runs significantly quicker. I'm not trying to pre-optimize; just weighing the pro's and con's of both methods. Is this typical of list comprehensions and should I expect linear behavior?

Comment: I'd guess it's because with the other methods itertools.product first creates a list of every possible combination of (a,b) and then tests every combination. Whereas, in the method above the any() method is short-circuited (as Steve Jessop pointed out) so that it will remove 'y' as soon as it finds a True value from meets_requirements() without testing further combinations. In general, I don't think itertools is slower if you actually need to test every combination, it's just not necessary in this case.

Comment: Also, both methods are O(n^2) not O(n) because for each element you have to test against all others elements.

Comment: I chose this Answer because not only do I feel it is very 'clean' and Pythonic -- it also helps with my specific use-case by avoiding the "to_be_removed" list and associated logic all together. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here. Though this is still equivalent to nested loops, but much more readable:

```
from itertools import product
for value1, value2 in product(my_list, repeat=2):
    if meets_requirements(value1, value2):
        to_be_removed.append(value2)
```

Comment: `itertools.product` is implemented in C, thus not quite the same.

Comment: @siebz0r I was talking in terms of Big-O time complexity. :-)

Comment: The advantage I see in using this method over List Comprehension is that it is much easier to digest and use for someone coming from a procedural background (other, future developers). Also, it's easier to include more logic during the comparison *if* need-be. Are there any other benefits I am over-looking?

Comment: IMHO list comprehension is more Pythonic, and I think you'll find that other python developers think it's easier to digest.

Answer (score 2):

I would have used a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) together with `product()` from the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import product
to_be_removed = [v2 for v1, v2 in product(mylist, repeat=2) 
                               if meets_requirement(v1, v2)]
```

Following @tobias_k's comment, if you don't want multiple instances of the same values in your result, and if the order of the elements doesn't matter, you can use a [set comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) instead:

```
to_be_removed = {v2 for v1, v2 in product(mylist, repeat=2) 
                               if meets_requirement(v1, v2)}
```

Comment: Don't know whether that's intentional, but this way `to_be_removed` may have many copies of `v2` in it.

Comment: @tobias_k: What do you mean? Each possible pair `v1, v2` will be checked and, if `meets_requirement()` returns `True`, `v2` will be added to the list, just as in the OP's code. I don't see the difference?

Comment: yes, there is no difference; it's the same behaviour as in OPs code. `v2` will be added *for each* `v1` with which it meets the requirements. I'm just wondering whether this behaviour is intentional in OPs code.

Comment: @tobias_k: Good point. I've added a set comprehension example as well.